# Missing outage postmortem for 2015-05-05

Tags: support, outage, stackstatus

The Stack Exchange network experienced a network-wide outage on May 5 (Note: due to timezone differences dates may be off by one):

> StackExchange Status ‏@StackStatus [May 5](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/595690502382604290)
>
> We are investigating a network-wide issue now.

Later on the same day, a postmortem report was promised:

> StackExchange Status ‏@StackStatus [May 5](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/595722551004942336)
>
> We have some cleanup work to do.  Plus we'll be writing up a postmortem report.  Thanks for your patience, folks!

Well, after waiting 6-8 weeks, my patience has run out. Where is this postmortem report?

FTR, the two latest posts on https://www.stackstatus.net are "Maintenance - June 8, 2015" and "Outage postmortem - March 31, 2015".

Comment: It takes 6-8 [something here]. In this case, it might be 6-8 months - better ask them again in January 5, 2016. Or, they might simply have no idea what happened. Happens too.

Comment: Maybe someone got so embarrassed that they don't dare to post it...